# Resolve return type of a generic function when type arguments are known

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Is it possible to get the resolved return type of a generic function when only its type and the desired type arguments are known?

For example, say I have a bunch of functions that transform strings:

```
const upperCaser = <Value extends string>
  (value: Value): Uppercase<Value> => value.toUpperCase() as Uppercase<Value>;
const lowerCaser = <Value extends string>
  (value: Value): Lowercase<Value> => value.toLowerCase() as Lowercase<Value>;
```

And I want to work with these generically using string values that are known static constants:

```
function transform<
  Value extends string,
  Transformer extends (arg0: Value) => any,
>(value: Value, transformer: Transformer): ReturnType<Transformer> {
  return transformer(value);
}

const myName = 'zaphod' as const;

const test = transform(myName, upperCaser);
```

I was hoping the type of `test` would be `'ZAPHOD'`, but it's unfortunately just `Uppercase<string>`. Is there some other way I can write this so that it resolves to the more specific type I was hoping for?

The ideal solution would be something like `ReturnType<Transformer<Value>>`, but that doesn't work because `Transformer` is a type argument rather than one that's defined generically. I've tried some custom implementations of `ReturnType` with different strategies, but they gave me the same result.

Is there any way to accomplish this? Both modifying the types and the signature of the functions is fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could define the generic parameter only for the return type, instead of the whole function and construct the type for the `transformer` using the types for value and return type:

```
function transform<Value extends string, R>(
  value: Value,
  transformer: (value: Value) => R,
): R {
  return transformer(value);
}
```

Testing:

```
const myName = 'zaphod' as const;

// "ZAPHOD"
const test = transform(myName, upperCaser);
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#code/MYewdgzgLgBArgBwQUwE4GECGE0wLwwA8AapgDZzIzIAeUyYAJhDNKgJZgDmAfABQA3cpQBcMUhWQBKMQFUkaYNmQlhyHvh4AoGDCGSAdFBDyUGZXykxsMU4uWrJPANxbQkWGRAB3NFhyo+EQSlNR0DMysUBzc-Pqi4moyMAAyPvY4jpQaeNq68chGIGm+5jiW1iwlGSoh6q5aAGZwYMBQ7OAw0ZiQjSCoALZZVLT0TCxsnFwANDAASvw6empiddNL3b39A2higiuJkla58+vJczAA3kuoyFBwqGBdqD0QfYNo+0euAL5abuBoDABgBPABymB2QQA5AAvTAIAAWIEY0MqMHc0AamNg9CBBE2b22fFBEJ2s0QZn8aCkriAA)

Comment: I could have sworn I tried this! Thank you!